# MEAN.Js application not work with production environment

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, openshift, meanjs

I have created application with MEAN.js and it works well when I set NODE_ENV to development. but when I change this to production and run the application than there is only blank page in the browser.

I searched for a long I found that I have to minify css & Js files using grunt.

so I do as below:

```
grunt build (which create 2 files in dist)
```

and than I run application but still I get the same result.

Also I want to this application on openshift but for grunt I have to download all Developer Dependencies and if I load all dependencies in openshift than it start giving error of disk space as in free account I have Inode limit of 80K only. so is there any other way to publish by application on openshift without loading all DevDependencies.?

Thanks

Comment: Build it localy than deploy to production environment.

Comment: I try to build it locally but in my local environment it also gives me white page for production.

Comment: Maybe error over minification phase? Try to disable all tasks in Grunt and enable them and check if this version works or not. You can run unit tests with minificated / production code - it should show where is the problem.

Comment: minified files are created. do i need to add this file anywhere to load. because I see resource folder in browser and there is no dist.min.css or dist.min.js files are loaded

Comment: Probable - yes. Applications that use JavaScript in some way must load … JavaScript files. I don’t know structure of your project, what you have done in Gruntfile but I guess that reason that you have white page is that you miss to add JS files to place from application is bootstrapping

Comment: Yes, you are right. my js file was missing. I add it manually and now it works as expected. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi @IleshPatel I am having a similar issue at the moment, my mean.js app is running in production :8443 on my localhost server, however when I upload to my production server, with NODE_ENV as production, my header loads for a second and I am left with a blank page. Do you have any guidance on this? Many thanks in advance -- Amy